# How do I make laravel throw an error if eloquent object attribute doesn't exist?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an eloquent model `$user` that contains the following attributes:

- id
- name

If I attempt to access an eloquent attribute that doesn't exist I will get null.

```
$user->address // is null
```

In php if you attempt to access an object attribute that doesn't exist you will get an error.

```
$x = (object)[];
$x->test // PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$test in Psy Shell code on line 1.
```

I'm not sure why eloquent has a different behaviour and it has caused me issues.

How do I make eloquent have the same behaviour as php?

Comment: What is your use case? Are you trying to make this validation when creating the `user`?

Comment: @HCK Specifically we had someone change a database table column name and they missed changing it in a blade. We never saw an error as it just returned null.

Comment: @hdifen I'd suggest that be approached via [testing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/testing) instead of tweaking Eloquent functionality.

Comment: @HCK yes we have testing. The issue was that when you are testing if you are using factories you can't assume the exact value. We could hard code all the values of our tests but that would be very time consuming. Perhaps we could assert not null for everything but arrrrrrrg

Comment: @HCK Just had a thought. If I call toArray() on our models when testing then test the array value we should get an error if it doesnt exist. Ugly but would probably protect from this edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses a ["magic method" called `__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) ([source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1511)) to handle undefined properties, for a variety of reasons (including handling relationships and accessor methods).

This behavior can't be turned off, as it'd break a bunch of other functionality.

Comment: Ok thanks, So your saying its not as simple as throwing an error inside the `HasAttributes::getAttribute()` method?

Comment: @hdifen Correct. That would break other useful functionality. For example, if you have a relationship function called `foo()`, `$this->foo` automatically fetches its results for the current model. If you have a `getFooAccessor()` function, it can be used to manipulate the value of `$this->foo` in useful ways. etc.

Comment: ah ok, I guess that there would be too many edge cases to handle to be able to reliably see if it's an error or not.

Answer (score 1):

As ceejayoz has said, this is a feature of Eloquent and can't be turned off. A solution however, is to use the `DB` facade to get records from the database that aren't eloquent models. Take the following example:

```
$userFromModel = User::first();
dd($userFromModel->notAnAttribute); // null

$userFromDBFacade = DB::table("user")->first();
dd($userFromDBFacade->notAnAttribute); // PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$notAnAttribute ...
```

This fallback only works for simple checks, and it might be more worthwhile to write a validation method for your Models to check for `null` properties.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea but yea. For consistency I'd have to do this everywhere which I don't really want to do.

Comment: Yeah, definitely understandable. And the `DB` facade just doesn't have as much usefulness as Eloquent models.